# Android: Error in R.Java <identifier> expected

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have copied this code from somewhere to create a Webview app with Splash screen. But, I keep getting this R.java error while building the app file:

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/Users/Varun/AndroidStudioProjects/DiagnoseECG/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/package com/abcofecg/app/diagnoseecg/R.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
package package com.abcofecg.app.diagnoseecg;
       ^
/Users/Varun/AndroidStudioProjects/DiagnoseECG/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/package com/abcofecg/app/diagnoseecg/R.java:8: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package package com.abcofecg.app.diagnoseecg;
                ^
/Users/Varun/AndroidStudioProjects/DiagnoseECG/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/package com/abcofecg/app/diagnoseecg/BuildConfig.java:4: error: <identifier> expected
package package com.abcofecg.app.diagnoseecg;
       ^
/Users/Varun/AndroidStudioProjects/DiagnoseECG/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/package com/abcofecg/app/diagnoseecg/BuildConfig.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package package com.abcofecg.app.diagnoseecg;
                ^
4 errors

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.302 secs
```

Please Help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with javascript. Code snippets are only for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do when something like this happens.

(1) Clean project/build
(2) Rebuild project 
(3) Sync Gradle
(4) Reboot Android Studio

Maybe one of these could solve your issue